# Sql Server CLR Functions

Tags: .net, sql-server, function, sqlclr

While writing a CLR function Sql Server can we use namespaces ?

```
namespace SomeName1.SomeName2
{
   public static class SomeClass
   {
       [SqlFunction]
       public static SqlString SomeMethod(SqlString input)
       {
          // ....
       }
   }
}
```

If so, then how do we call this function from SqlServer. In other words how do we call CLR functions from SQL Server with namespaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SomeMethod(@input VarChar(200))
RETURNS VarChar(200) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER AS

EXTERNAL NAME [SomeName1.SomeName2].[SomeName1.SomeName2.SomeClass.SomeMethod]
```

Where `[SomeName1.SomeName2]` in the first part is the assembly as named in SQL Server, and the rest (`[SomeName1.SomeName2.SomeClass.SomeMethod]`) is the fully qualified function name, including the namespace.

Incidentally, if you deploy from Visual Studio it handles a lot of this for you.

Comment: I just figured that out. I was about to answer that. [AssemblyName][Namespace.Class].[Method]. Thanks !

Comment: It would actually be [AssemlyName] then the rest goes as [SomeName1.SomeName2.SomeClass].[SomeMethod]

Comment: Correct. I'm assuming your assembly name follows that of the namespace being defined here.

Comment: @Debjit - just a typo correction to your comment: [AssemblyName].[Namespace.Class].[Method]. Thanks!